# How to get all possible combinations of strings from List<string[]>?

Tags: c#, list, iteration, combinations

I'm doing a tag-like string match function where function checks is string contains any of possible words while maintaining their order, at least per tag.
I figured out it will be best to precreate list of possibilities and on check simply see if string contains each of required combinations

Maybe code will make it more clear.

```
List<List<string[]>> tags;

List<string[]> innerList;

List<List<string>> combinationsList;

public void Generate(string pattern)
{
    // i will add whitespace removal later so it can be ", " instead of only ","

    foreach (string tag in pattern.Split(','))
    {
        innerList = new List<string[]>();

        foreach (var varyword in tag.Split(' '))
        {
            innerList.Add(varyword.Split('|'));
        }
    }

    // atm i lack code to generate combinations in form of List<List<string>> 
    // and drop them into 'combinationsList'
}

// the check function will look something like isMatch = :
public bool IsMatch(string textToTest)
{
    return combinationsList.All(tc => tc.Any(c => textToTest.Contains(c)));
}
```

So for example pattern:

**"old|young john|bob, have|posses dog|cat"**

- tags:

  - List_1:

    - {old, young}
    - {john, bob}
  - List_2

    - {have, posses}
    - {dog, cat}

So combinationsList will have:

- combinationsList :

  - List_1

    - "old john"
    - "old bob"
    - "young john"
    - "young bob"
  - List_2

    - "have dog"
    - "have cat"
    - "posses dog"
    - "posses cat"

So results will be:

- old bob have cat = true, contains List_1:"old bob" and List_2:"have cat"
- young john have car = false, contains List_1:"young john" but doesn't contain any of List_2 combinations

I cannot figure out how to iterate collection to get those combinations and how to get the combination per iteration.
Also i cannot mess up the order so old john will not be also generated as john old.

Please note that any of "variant words" in pattern may have more than 2 variants like for example "dog|cat|mouse"

Comment: Try two nested foreach loops over the `List`s.

Comment: if your list has less than 32 elements  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10515693/659190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in another thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11110641/1156272

The code posted by [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898289/adam) works flawlessly and does exactly what i needed

```
        foreach (var tag in pattern.Split(','))
        {
            string tg = tag;
            while (tg.StartsWith(" ")) tg = tg.Remove(0,1);
            innerList = new List<List<string>>();

            foreach (var varyword in tg.Split(' '))
            {
                innerList.Add(varyword.Split('|').ToList<string>());
            }

            //Adam's code

            List<String> combinations = new List<String>();
            int n = innerList.Count;
            int[] counter = new int[n];
            int[] max = new int[n];
            int combinationsCount = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                max[i] = innerList[i].Count;
                combinationsCount *= max[i];
            }
            int nMinus1 = n - 1;
            for (int j = combinationsCount; j > 0; j--)
            {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append(innerList[i][counter[i]]);
                    if (i < n - 1) builder.Append(" "); //my addition to insert whitespace between words
                }
                combinations.Add(builder.ToString());

                counter[nMinus1]++;
                for (int i = nMinus1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    // overflow check
                    if (counter[i] == max[i])
                    {
                        if (i > 0)
                        {
                            // carry to the left
                            counter[i] = 0;
                            counter[i - 1]++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //end

            if(combinations.Count > 0)
                combinationsList.Add(combinations);
        }
    }

    public bool IsMatch(string textToCheck)
    {
        if (combinationsList.Count == 0) return true;

        string t = _caseSensitive ? textToCheck : textToCheck.ToLower();

        return combinationsList.All(tg => tg.Any(c => t.Contains(c)));
    }
```

Looks like magic but it works. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

This code may help

```
string pattern = "old|young john|bob have|posses dog|cat";
var lists = pattern.Split(' ').Select(p => p.Split('|'));

foreach (var line in CartesianProduct(lists))
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ",line));
}


//http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    // base case:
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> result = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    foreach (var sequence in sequences)
    {
        var s = sequence; // don't close over the loop variable
        // recursive case: use SelectMany to build the new product out of the old one
        result =
            from seq in result
            from item in s
            select seq.Concat(new[] { item });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, i would prefer simple foreach iterations if it's possible so i can understand clearly what is going on.

also please note that combinations should not be in reverse order so A|B C|D will not yield C A or D B etc

I know it sounds little ignorant but i prefer to learn step by step instead of simply copy paste :)

Comment: @Nerfpl If you see the output, combinations are not reversed. they preserve the order. But I can't do anything for simple iterations(sorry, too lazy for this). Maybe someone would post that solution.